# Is there a way to conditionally set number of array dimensions?

Tags: php

I need to write something like

```
            if($flag) {
                $data['record'] = $item['currentData'];
            } else {
                $data['record']['date'] = $item['currentData'];
            }
```

Is there a way to do it simpler? without the if statement on every call?

I've wondered if something similar to the code below is possible.

```
$data['record'] + $flag && ['date'] = $item['currentData'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so.  And even if there was, you'd still be testing the value of `$flag` and possibly making the code harder to read.  What's your objective?

Comment: Why do you have a variable data structure like this in the first place?

Comment: You can do `$data['record'] = $flag ? $item['currentData'] : ['date' => $item['currentData']];`, if you really think that is helpful here.